# How to print the time in c/unix with gettimeofday()

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, time

I am trying to write the time in format of **21-02-2016 00:50:00** but there are some mistakes that I could not solve. Also in main function I called `PrintTime()` and I got an undefined reference error in main function which is probably because of this piece of code.

```
void PrintTime()
{
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t nowtime;
  struct tm *nowtm;
  char tmbuf[64]

  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  nowtime = tv.tv_sec;
  nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
  strftime(tmbuf, sizeof tmbuf, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm);
  free(tmbuf);
}
```

I tried to execute this here are the list of errors I get:

```
Q3.c:67:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
 nowtm = localtime(&nowtime);
       ^
Q3.c:68:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strftime’
 strftime(tmbuf, sizeof tmbuf, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", nowtm);
 ^
/tmp/ccwQwMjE.o: In function `main':
Q3.c:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `PrintTime'
```

Comment: I'd guess that you didn't include the correct headers, and didn't link to the file with the `PrintTime` function. For a better answer, a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed, along with the command line that you used to build the program.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to use "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS", use the ISO 8601 standard format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". It's an international standard, it's unambiguous, and it sorts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have `#include <time.h>` included in it

```
/* PrintTime.h */
#ifndef PRINTTIME_H
#define PRINTTIME_H
...
#include <time.h>
...

void PrintTime(){

}
```

And the `main.c`

```
/* main.c */
...
#include <PrintTime.h>
...

int main() {
 ...
 return 0;
}
```

Compiling

```
% cc main.c -o main -I_path_to_PrintTime_h_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` after `char tmbuf[64]`. `free(tmbuf);` is wrong because `tmbuff` is declared as Stack not Heap. Revise and compile again. Be sure that you are already included

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
```